# Wine directx interpreter broken after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, wine, 22.04, opengl

Recently I upgrade my Ubuntu distro from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS, and after that to 22.04 LTS.

Having wine-staging 7.17 installed, after the upgrade to 22.04 I can't launch my directx games (only opengl based games are still runing). That's what I get, for example, launching Out Run 2006:

```
arcade@CReTro:~/roms/windows/OutRun 2006 - Coast 2 Coast$ wine OR2006C2C.EXE
002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk wine-staging 7.17 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
002c:fixme:winediag:LdrInitializeThunk Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
006c:fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {e2821408-c59d-418f-ad3f-aa4e792aeb79}
006c:err:winediag:ntlm_check_version ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
006c:err:ntlm:ntlm_LsaApInitializePackage no NTLM support, expect problems
006c:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation handle 0000000001D80000, info_class 0, info 000000000011FD80, size 4 stub!
006c:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation handle 0000000000230000, info_class 1, info 0000000000000000, size 0 stub!
0080:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity 000000000026B380, -1, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 4, 2, 0000000000000000, 0, 0000000000000000 stub
00a0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a0:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0080:fixme:ole:CoResumeClassObjects stub
0130:fixme:crypt:Collection_release Unimplemented flags 1
0130:fixme:crypt:ProvStore_release Unimplemented flags 1
0130:fixme:crypt:CRYPT_RegCloseStore Unimplemented flags: 00000001
0130:fixme:crypt:MemStore_release Unimplemented flags 1
002c:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021FDB0 0000000000000000): stub
0034:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021FDB0 0000000000000000): stub
0074:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010034, 0): stub
0074:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (000000000001002E, 0000000000010034): stub
0140:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00010072, 1): stub
0140:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010074, 00010072): stub
0130:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0000000002C7E8D8, overlapped 00000000012166C8): stub
0130:fixme:wtsapi:WTSEnumerateSessionsW Stub 0000000000000000 0x00000000 0x00000001 0000000002C7E8D8 0000000002C7E8D4
0140:err:wgl:init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
0140:err:wgl:init_opengl OpenGL support is disabled.
0140:err:d3d:wined3d_caps_gl_ctx_create Failed to find a suitable pixel format.
0140:err:d3d:wined3d_adapter_gl_init Failed to get a GL context for adapter 01886680.
0138:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (000000000021FDB0 0000000000000000): stub
arcade@CReTro:~/roms/windows/OutRun 2006 - Coast 2 Coast$ 0154:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation handle 0000000001B80000, info_class 0, info 000000000011FDF0, size 4 stub!
0154:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation handle 0000000000230000, info_class 1, info 0000000000000000, size 0 stub!
0154:fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (000000000025D0A8, 000000000025C8A8, 2048, 0x0): semi-stub
0130:fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationInitialize (0000000002C7EFD0, 0000000002C7F160, 2048, 0x0): semi-stub
0130:fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (0000000002C7EFD0): stub
0154:fixme:ole:NdrCorrelationFree (000000000025D0A8): stub
```

Can you help to fix this?

Many thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

In Fact, OpenGL games, In my case, fail the same way, but simply issue an error at init without a crash dump

Ex: TSC, launched from wineconsole:

Failed to find a suitable pixel format for device context: Descripteur de fenêtre invalide. Cannot create OpenGL context

I use the wine 7.0.1 stable branch for operations in Q4wine, but In playOnLinux, it seems to happen whatever the version I use